# postgresql Converting WKB to utm

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I am using PostgreSQL with postgis, the geometries are in UTM and stored as WKB with several shapes types (point, polygon, linestring...). Is there a way to convert the wkb to a list of points in radians or utm? without the string parsing of the shape type and each point? 
thanks

Comment: The guys at http://gis.stackexchange.com may be able to help you more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

There are [a whole set of geometry accessors](http://www.postgis.org/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Accessors) to get exactly what you need, e.g. `ST_AsText(geom)` to get [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) or `ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)` to get [GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON).

To translate from UTM to degrees longitude and latitude (in that axis order), use `ST_Transform(geom, 4326)`. I've never seen coordinates as radians, but you could first convert to WGS84 (SRID=4326), then use, e.g. `ST_X(geom) * pi() / 180` for points. For other geometries, you would need to use `ST_DumpPoints` to get to the coordinates.